# Which BIOS does Samsung ATIV Book 9 Spin have?

Tags: bios

The [support page](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/notebook-nine-spin) has nothing about BIOS updates, and I can't even figure out which actual BIOS is installed. The only information I have is the BIOS/MICOM version listed in the BIOS itself, which are both "P08AFD", and the fact that the BIOS is produced by AMI and runs something called Aptio Setup Utility (no idea which version) from 2015. Finding updates for that seems to be impossible.

Comment: Why are you looking for BIOS information? The fact there are no downloads available for this system indicates there are no updated packages beyond those shipped with the computer originally.

Comment: I'd like to be able to download BIOS updates from the source (AMI) without having to wait for Samsung to update their site. But without knowing which BIOS it is I can't even download the right update program from AMI.

Comment: Don't. Just don't. Samsung may have purchased an AMI bios, but they wrote their own code for it. Unless you have a very reason to do so, you should only download bios updates for this computer from Samsung.

Comment: Oh, OK. Didn't think custom BIOS firmware would be worth it for them. It doesn't contain any Samsung branding at all, either.

Answer (score 0):

The BIOS firmware contains switches and options which are enabled or disabled depending on the hardware it will be running. The OEM sets these to correlate to the specific features of the model it is designed for. It may be possible to run default AMI firmware on your BIOS, and it may even work OK, but there's a greater chance that there will be issues.

If you wish to find the specific BIOS model, you may try one of the various sytem information utilities, such as **CPU-Z**, or the **System Information** utility built-in to Windows.